# Compile-time check that all array values are filled

Tags: c++, compile-time, static-assert

This:

```
constexpr const std::array<int, 3> {{
  0,
  1
}};
```

compiles OK.

But how to check (in compile-time) that whole array is filled? May be some `static_assert`?

Comment: What do you mean by "filled"? Do you mean initialized?

Comment: @TartanLlama Yes, initialized. Check that programmer not forgot to add a value after changing size.

Comment: There is no way to test whether an object has been initialized or not, but I think the remaining elements are value-initialized (i.e. zero in your case). (In other words, it works like a vanilla array.)

Comment: Yeah, unless you'd need to write a wrapper function to make the array for you; you can't tell after-the-fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a wrapper to generate the array for you and carry out the check:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N, typename... Ts>
std::array<T, N> make_array (Ts&&... ts) {
    static_assert(N == sizeof...(Ts), "Must supply N arguments");
    return {{ std::forward<Ts>(ts)... }};   
}
```

But with that function you may as well just deduce the size of the array from the arguments:

```
template <typename T, typename... Ts>
std::array<T, sizeof...(Ts)> make_array (Ts&&... ts) {
    return {{ std::forward<Ts>(ts)... }};   
}
```

Comment: TartanLlama, why I cannot make it constexpr? Clang 3.8.1 says that `non-constexpr function 'forward<int>' cannot be used in a constant expression
            return {{ std::forward<Ts>(ts)... }};` ?

Comment: @vladon `std::forward` is unfortunately not `constexpr` in c++11 (see [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3305.html)). If you're just going to use built-in or small types, you could just pass by value, or pass by const ref instead. Alternatively, you could write a `constexpr` forward function.

Comment: But I use `-std=c++14`...

Comment: @vladon Hmm, can you post an example? [This](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/133525bfe3972ba0) seems to work fine.

Comment: Sorry, it's my bad, somehow I use old libcxx with clang, where std::forward isn't constexpr :(

Answer (score 1):

As an enhancement to TartanLlama answer i would wrap the initializing routine into another macro to provide the possibility to create proper documentation and better readability (Since the op mentioned that this is a safety check for other programmers).

```
template <typename T, T ...ts>
struct ArrayInitializer { 
    const std::array<T, sizeof...(ts)> ARRAY = {{ ts... }}; 
};

/*
 * @document me
 */
#define MAKE_ARRAY(name, ...) \
    constexpr const auto name = ArrayInitializer<int,  ##__VA_ARGS__ >().ARRAY;

// Create array with x elements    
MAKE_ARRAY(arrayName, 1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Comment: How is that better than `auto arrayName = make_array(1,2,3,4);` ?  (Particularly as `##__VA_ARGS__` is not blessed by the standard.)

Comment: The way the initialization is done is not in question, since both of the approaches are only used at compile time and serve the same purpose, my point was to provide a readable interface to other programmers that use the array, especially when parsing the sources with doxygen, etc...

Comment: In fact  __VA_ARGS__ is part of the standard.
Quote Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_macro):
"Variable-argument macros were introduced in 1999 in the ISO/IEC 9899:1999 (C99) revision of the C language standard, and in 2011 in ISO/IEC 14882:2011 (C++11) revision of the C++ language standard."

Comment: Yes I know `__VA_ARGS__` is part of the standard - it is preceding it with `##` (the preprocessor token-pasting operator) that is non-standard (although a common extension).

Comment: Using a macro for this seems really ugly and unnecessary. What part of that is more readable and documentable than my answer? Even if you've never written a template in your life, `auto arr = make_array<int>(1,2,3);` seems pretty self-documenting to me.